# Как добавить один спиок в другой в BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, парсер, список, beautiful-soup

У меня есть парсер, которой пасрит названия товаров, но я хочу еще добавить id для этого списка, как мне это сделать?

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-argonodugovoy-svarki-tig'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_html_vivod(html):
    svarka = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-products')
    for item in items:  
        svarka.append({
            #id - здесь должен быть айди
            "text": item.find('div', class_='b-products__title').get_text(strip=True)
            })
    return svarka

html = get_html(URL)
print(get_html_vivod(html.text))
```

Comment: В чём проблема? Найти этот id? Сгенерировать?

Comment: Там нету айди, и я хочу дать собственный

Answer (score 0):

Раз проблема в генерации `id`, то надо решить, как его генерировать. Первые 2 варианта, пришедшие в голову:

### [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```py
...
for idx, item in enumerate(items):  
        svarka.append({
            "id": idx
            "text": item.find('div', class_='b-products__title').get_text(strip=True)
            })
...
```

В таком случае `id` будет инкрементироваться с каждой итерацией (0, 1, 2 и т.д.).

### [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#module-uuid)

```py
from uuid import uuid4
...
for item in enumerate(items):  
        svarka.append({
            "id": str(uuid4())
            "text": item.find('div', class_='b-products__title').get_text(strip=True)
            })
...
```

Так каждый раз будут генеирироваться уникальные идентификаторы, похожие на `13a7a512-4aef-4162-9c6e-5a5b181534b8`.

Comment: Но мне нужно сделать айди, не такой, что начинается с цифры 1, а мне нужно, чтобы начиналось с цифры к примеру 2651, это как нибудь возможно сделать?

Comment: Нельзя ли сделать, этот айди к примеру через метод: for i in range(2561, 2600)?

Comment: `for idx, item in enumerate(items, start=2561):`

Comment: А еще вопрос, как добавить из одного списка элементы в список svarka?

Comment: `svarka.extend(drugoy_spisok)`.

Comment: Не работает добавление другого списка